# Replace a picture with Office-js

Tags: office365, office-js

**Background Info**

Currently working on a office-js add that will be used to modify inline images in a documents.

**Question**

The ideal situation is to select a specific image that is already inside a document and replace them with another image.  Now Ideal I thought I can click on the image and run a `var range = context.document.getSelection();` in order to load the selection, but I am not able to load the selected image and replace it with the new image. Unless I actually clear it.

**Code**

```
Word.run(function (context) {
        var range = context.document.getSelection();
        context.load(range)
        return context.sync().then(function () {           
            range.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(base64, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
            console.log('Added base64 encoded text to the beginning of the range.');
        });
    })
```

**Update**

This block of code is able to insert the image where I want it too, however when I am trying to add sizing it is I am getting the following error.

**Updated Code**

```
function insertImageToDoc(base64, selectedContent) {
    Word.run(function (context) {

        var range = context.document.getSelection();
        var paragraphs = range.paragraphs;
        context.load(paragraphs);

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            var para = paragraphs.items[0];
            var image = para.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(base64, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
            image.width = selectedContent.ImageWidth;
            image.height = selectedContent.Imageheight;              
        });
    })
};
```

**Error this Code is giving me**

[image]

Comment: I thought your problem was calling `insertInlinePicture` after the sync instead of before. But actually your way should work too because of the implicit ctx.sync. Trying it on my computer, it works the way you expect. Can you explain what you mean by "not placed in the correct spot"? Where is the image placed? Does your initial selection contain more than just the image?

Comment: @Michael Saunders , I just put an update of my code, my main objective is to replace the picture with the new one and give it a custom size.

Comment: the problem with your code is that you are not replacing the image, you are replacing the entire  paragraph! check my example is retrieving the image or images within the selection and then replacing them.

Comment: **Very important** to point out that the height and width will have to go in the specific order.  First is the height and then it's the width.  If you do width and height the image resize will not work correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to delete the images. You just need to replace it.

A few recommendations:

1. For any given range you can have access to the inlinePictures collection, so your first instruction is to get the selection and all the inlinePictures within it.
2. Once you have that you can iterate through the collection, as you traverse the images within the collection you can get the original width and height and use it later if needed maybe you want to keep the doc structure and for that is necessary to know the existing image size, You can also get  other properties in images (i.e. alt title and description, useful if you want to tag specific images.

   3. Finally your code looks ok you can call the insertInlinePictures with a "replace" insertLocation, the only part that you are missing is that you need to call context.sync again so the instruction gets executed by Word.

Here is some sample code that is doing everything I mentioned:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
            // here is how you access the inline pictures on the selection:
            var myImages = context.document.getSelection().inlinePictures;
            context.load(myImages);

            return context.sync().then(function () {
                if (myImages.items.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; myImages.items.length; i++) {
                        //you could get the current image with and height if needed, so you replace use the same real estate.
                        var currentHeight = myImages.items[i].height;
                        var currentWidth = myImages.items[i].width;
// this is the instruction to replace the image:
                        var myNewImage = myImages.items[i].insertInlinePictureFromBase64(ImageBase64(), "replace");
                        return context.sync()  // very important you need to context.sync again



                    }
                }

            });
        }).catch(function (e) {
            app.showNotification(e.message);

        })
```